# Eclipse Mars has different system variables while debugging

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a problem with system variables when running program in debug mode. I use Eclipse Mars and Windows 8.1.

I am trying to create temp file using: `Path pacFilePath = Files.createTempFile("pac-" + tunnelIdentifier, ".js");`

As I know, it looks for java.io.tmpdir variable, that points to TMP system variable. My TMP and TEMP variables are point to `C:\Users\ULADZI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\`.
`java -XshowSettings` shows that `java.io.tmpdir = C:\Users\ULADZI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\`.
When I simply run my program, everything is ok. But it throws an exception in debug mode:
`java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\WINDOWS\pac-pool-2-thread-18102797590563474039.js`

Should I configure eclipse in some special way or is it eclipse bug?

Comment: Try with some other stack site ! Not sure if SO is the correct place for this.